# A bijection cannot be the composition of an injective and a surjective function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Can someone explain me visually how it is conceivable  that having f: Y --> Z and g: X --> Y  and f o g: X --> Z then f is injective and g is surjective is FALSE

Comment: Is the new title I propose a correct one ?

Comment: A few things: first, it is possible that the composition $f\circ g$ is a bijection- you could have $X=Y=Z$ and $f=g$ be the identity map. The problem is that, as Noah Schweber's answer explains, it is possible for $f$ to not be injective and $g$ to not be surjective, and yet for $f\circ g$ to still be a bijection. Second, you might be confusing this with another statement: that if $f\circ g$ is a bijection, then $f$ must be surjective and $g$ must be injective.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, $Y$ could have lots of "extraneous" elements.

Consider, for example, the sets $X=Z=\{1\}$ and $Y=\{1,2\}$, let $g$ be the identity map, and let $f$ be the constant map sending $1$ and $2$ to $1$. Then:

- $g$ is not surjective: it misses $2$.
- $f$ is not injective: it sends $1$ and $2$ to the same thing.

But these errors cancel out: the element $2\in Y$ is ignored by $g$, and so it doesn't matter that it's treated poorly by $f$. The composition $$f\circ g: X\rightarrow Z$$ is indeed a bijection (in fact it's the identity map).

---

We *can* show that in order for $f\circ g$ to be bijective $f$ has to be injective *when we restrict attention to $im(g)\subseteq Y$*. Similarly, we can conclude that $g$ must be injective and $f$ must be surjective, basically because failures of these properties can't be "fixed" in the manner above (this is a good exercise).